# NameError: name 'buffer' is not defined with Ant Based framework batch file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, python-2.5

I'm using a python script to execute an Ant based framework batch file(Helium.bat)

`subprocess.Popen('hlm '+commands, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`

However the script will always stop and display the following error when it executes the .bat file:

```
import codecs
  File "C:\Python25\lib\codecs.py", line 1007, in <module>
    strict_errors = lookup_error("strict")
  File "C:\Python25\lib\codecs.py", line 1007, in <module>
    strict_errors = lookup_error("strict")
  File "C:\Python25\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    import codecs, types
  File "C:\Python25\lib\types.py", line 36, in <module>
    BufferType = buffer
NameError: name 'buffer' is not defined
```

If I execute the .bat directly on command line, there will not be any issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think at least part of the problem is how you're executing the batch file. Give this a try:

```
# execute the batch file as a separate process and echo its output
Popen_kwargs = { 'stdout': subprocess.PIPE, 'stderr': subprocess.STDOUT,
                 'universal_newlines': True }
with subprocess.Popen('hlm '+commands, **Popen_kwargs).stdout as output:
    for line in output:
        print line,
```

This pass different arguments to `Popen` -- the difference are this version removes the `shell=True` which isn't needed on a batch file, sets `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` which redirects `stdout` to the same place stdout is going to to avoid missing any error messages, and adds a `universal_newlines=True` to make the output more readable.

Another difference is it reads and prints the output from the `Popen` process which will effectively make the Python script running the batch file wait until it's finished executing before continuing on -- which I suspect is important.

Comment: @BiX: Very unlikely that codecs.py has a SyntaxError in it -- must be whatever file has the line of code with the `no viable alternative at input '""'` in it. You're likely getting the glade `ImportError` because it needs to be re-installed following your Python upgraded (it's not a standard Python library module).

Comment: These errors will not occur if I just use the batch file in command line instead of executing it from the python script.

Sadly I've tried re-installing glade many times and it still didn't work =/

Comment: @BiX: I didn't realize that was what you were doing. Update your question to show *how* you're executing the batch file -- sounds like that might be at least part of the problem.