# Calling bat file from python with input prompt

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, batch-file, subprocess

Need help in calling `.bat` file via python in windows server.

Currently the `.bat` file is used to encrypt the password and generate password  file .

when the admin run this `.bat` file, they ll execute below command

`runbatch.bat filename`

On executing the above it prompt us to enter password

`....Enter the password to encrypt`

On entering the password it generate the password file in the specified folder.

Now the requirement is to call this `.bat` file via python.
Reason behind this to create an API and give option to user to generate the password file from their end. When user tries to generate the password file it prompts for password and password file name and passes those parameters to python script which in return calls a `.bat` file

I am not sure how to echo password input as we do directly in `cmd`.

`Echo password| runbatch.bat filename`

In python I have defined `.bat` location on `os.dir` and using `popen` `subprocess option to run the`.bat` but not sure how to pass password to the command.

```
 import sys 
 import os 
 import subprocess 
 sPassword = $Password 
 sPasswordFile = $PasswordFile 
 sInstance = "D:/API/bin" os.chdir(sInstance) 
 ScriptName = sInstance + "/encryptpassword.bat" 
 command = '%s "%s"' % (ScriptName, sPasswordFile) 
 p = subprocess.Popen(command) retcode = p.wait()
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please paste a python script file and contents of the working directory so that it's easy to figure the problem.

Comment: I think you might find my answer to the (mostly unrelated) question [Run multiple programs sequentially in one Windows command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415134/run-multiple-programs-sequentially-in-one-windows-command-prompt) handles I/O with `subprocess.Popen()` helpful. There's a simpler example in my answer to [NameError: name 'buffer' is not defined with Ant Based framework batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427494/nameerror-name-buffer-is-not-defined-with-ant-based-framework-batch-file).

Comment: Hi Martineau, Thanks for your response. Will look in to the link and get back to you if any questions.

Comment: @sarv2k: OK, but be sure to prefix my username with an `@` character so I will be notified — the only reason I'm responding now is because I happened to take a look at your question again.

Comment: @@sarv2k: Also, please paste that `.bat` file's code _into your question_, not down here in a comment (where it's very hard to read).

Comment: @Martineau, once again thanks for guiding.

Comment: @ajmartin, Thanks for your response. updated the code.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand the requirements

Comment: @Pitto , no sorry I do read my question back and its difficult to get the requirement clearly. In simple I am trying to call the .bat file via python and this .bat file will prompt for user input so I am looking to run this .bat by taking input from variable which is already declared.

Comment: Start easy before complicating things. Try to understand how to feed password to your batch script without python just using the command prompt. Does it work if you use a text file containing the password? example:   your_batch.bat < password.txt

Comment: Refer to this answer -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/165662